# Saving data into profile model does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue with associating two models in my rails application: Users & Profiles. An individual user profile should be created after a new user signs up. After signing up the user, saving data into the actual profile model is not successful. I can not get it to work. Please find a detailed description below.

**Here is my setup:**

I use Rails 4.0.0.rc2 and ruby 2.0.0p195.

Both models are associated like this:

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  before_create :build_profile
```

As I use the `devise gem`I have created a `registrationscontroller`to change the after_sign_up_path:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_profile_path(:user_id => @user)
  end
end
```

Whenever I sign up a new user the actual sign up works fine, the user is subsequently being directed to `http://localhost:3000/users/42/profile/new` for example. However, when I then enter the data into the profile form fields and click on submit I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/profile"
```

Although one could expect a routing error, you will notice a different error when looking at the actual domain:

```
http://localhost:3000/users//profile
```

In case you still want to have a look at my `routes.rb` please do (relevant excerpt):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'signup', :to => "devise/registrations#new", as: :signup
    get 'login', :to => "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get 'logout', :to => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
  end

  resources :users do
      resource :profile
  end
```

However, as noted above I don't really have a routing issue. It rather seems like I have an issue with the current user_id not being properly shown in the domain, which can be related to either my actual profile form or the new action on the profiles controller.

I start my profile form on new.html.erb like this:

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

My `profiles_controller.rb`looks like this:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      #@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      @profile = current_user.profile
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:photo, :address, :zip, :city, :state, :country, :telephone, :experience, :levels, :ages, :travel, :teachinglocation, :onlineteaching, :quotation, :aboutme, :subjects, :specialties, :lessondetails, :equipment)
    end
end
```

What do I do wrong? How can I properly ensure that a newly signed up user can properly save his profile data?

It would be so great, if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Profile controller is not configured with the correct url - as can be seen by the missing User ID information.

You can see all currently defined paths by running the command `rake routes` from the command line.

*I am a beginner at RESTful design and Rails, so do not consider the following expert advice.*

Try changing the location of your redirect_to in the Profile create method:

```
# POST /profiles
# POST /profiles.json
def create
 ...
    format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(@profile.user, @profile), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
 ...
```

If this works, the path should also be updated in the update and delete methods. As well as the format.json sections.

For additional info about this topic see:
2.9 Creating Paths and URLs From Objects
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html